Why I am getting FileNotFoundException when starting a web application using smart tomcat plugin via Intellijidea community edition?

I'm working on a Java 8 Web Application with Spring. It is a simple Web-Application which is being built via maven into a war-File. My IDE is Intellij IDEA Community, the application is being deployed with Intellij to a Tomcat 9.0.97. The build process uses two Maven profiles.
If I try to start the application via an Intellij plugin smartTomcat Run Configuration, I am every time, I get FileNotFoundException. If I check for the "missing" xmls then I find them, they are all where they are supposed to be ("<%Project_Root%>\target\webapp\WEB-INF\lib") but where Intellij says they aren't
